# custom glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I would like to change the `glossaries` settings in order to have " see p. x" rather than just the number of the page where this entry is.

For example if the acronym PC in the page 3 of my document, it will appear in the glossary as
" PC Personal Computer. 3", and I would like " PC Personal Computer. see p. 3"

How can I do that ? I read the user-guide of the `glossaries` package but I did not find (or understant) something about it.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside,openright,a4paper,11pt]{report}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage{makeidx}                % package permettant de crÃ©er des index
\usepackage[toc,acronym,xindy,section=section]{glossaries} 
\newglossary[ntg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Glossaire}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

 \makeindex             % 
 \makeglossaries        %


 \begin{document}       % 

\newglossaryentry{glscard}{%type=main,
      name=cardinality,
        description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main]

\newacronym{pc}{PC}{personal computer}


\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym]


\newglossaryentry{mesh}{type=notation,
    name={Mesh},
    description={maillage},
    sort={m}}

\printglossary[type=notation]

\newglossaryentry{mbb}{type=symbols,    
    name={\ensuremath{ {M} }},
    first={dzq},                        
    firstplural={esfe}
    text={ \uuline{M} },                
    plural={fesfse},                    
    description={matrix},               
    descriptionplural={desfsf},
    sort=m,                             
    see=[see also]{glscard}}                        

\printglossary[type=symbols]

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

 \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \gls{mbb}; \gls{mesh};

 \end{document}
```

Note the cross-reference does not work, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displaying of glossaries is controlled by the styles. Then you need declare a new style or edit the macros that used into the styles.  The defualt style is `list` and the part that print the entries in the glossaries is the `\glossentry` *macro*.

The *list style* definition declares the `\glossentry` *macro* as (p. 251, [glossaries-code.pdf](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-code.pdf#251)):

```
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
\item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
```

Then is possible to define a new style based in the *list style* (p. 179, [glossaries-user.pdf](http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf#179)), and modify only the `\glossentry` *macro* adding the 'see p.' before of `page list` part (##2). It means:

```
\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
\setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
\item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space see p.\space ##2}%
}
```

Finally, it is necessary set the style before of the *print glossary*

```
\setglossarystyle{mylist}
```

The last question about the *cross-reference*: this works if the `newglossaryentry` are used in the `preamble`. I don't know the reason, I think is related to that:

> Originally, \newglossaryentry ... could only be used in the preamble.(p. 83, [glossaries-user.pdf](http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf#83))

MWE:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside,openright,a4paper,11pt]{report}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage{makeidx}                % package permettant de crÃ©er des index
\usepackage[toc,acronym,xindy,section=section]{glossaries} 

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
    \setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space see p.\space ##2}%
}



\newglossary[ntg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Glossaire}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

 \makeindex             % 
 \makeglossaries        %

\newglossaryentry{glscard}{%type=main,
      name=cardinality,
        description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

\newglossaryentry{mesh}{type=notation,
    name={Mesh},
    description={maillage},
    sort={m}}

\newglossaryentry{mbb}{type=symbols,    
    name={\ensuremath{ {M} }},
    first={dzq},                        
    firstplural={esfe}
    text={ \uuline{M} },                
    plural={fesfse},                    
    description={matrix},               
    descriptionplural={desfsf},
    sort=m,                             
    see=[see also]{glscard}} 

 \begin{document}       % 

\setglossarystyle{mylist}    
\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main]
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{personal computer}   
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym]
\printglossary[type=notation]



\printglossary[type=symbols]

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

 \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \gls{mbb}; \gls{mesh};

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is working great when I compile with arara. But if after the arara compilation, I compile with pdflatex I get an error message : "(./essai2.out) ! Undefined control sequence. l.48 \setglossarystyle{mylist} ?" How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: @Romain, hi. I ran `arara`  and after `pdflatex`, but didn't obtain the error. you can try delete the auxiliary files and try again.

Comment: I delete all the auxiliary files, and this didn't chage anything. In fact I run pdflatex through TexMaker, the error could be linked to TexMaker ?

Comment: If you run the `arara` and `pdflatex` from console, do you get the same error?

Comment: Hi. If run `arara` and `pdflatex` from console I don't get any error. But I tried today with another computer at work and I didn't get any error with `TexMaker`. I don't know what makes the difference but it's ok. Thanks.

Otherwise, do you know how can I get the number of arguments in the list ##2 in the command `newglossarystyle` ? I try to creat a counter but it doesn't understant ##2 as a list but as a string.